# Why SRV res_query always returns -1?

Tags: c++, dns, srv

I'm trying to implement a simple DNS SRV query by using `res_query`. My code for the res_query part is following:

```
char* target;
short* port;

union {
    HEADER hdr;
    u_char buf[1024];
} response;

ns_msg handle;
ns_rr rr;
u_char buf[256], *p;
int t, len, priority, weight;

if ((len = res_query(query, C_IN, ns_t_srv, (u_char *)&response, sizeof(response))) <0 ) {
    cout << "res_query returned -1, no answer" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

This is just a part of the code, but I guess there's all the required things to do the `res_query`. Every time I execute the SRV query, the res_query returns '-1', meaning it fails. Is the problem in my res_query or am I doing something else wrong?

I've tried to do the SRV query to `www.example.com`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`res_query` will return -1 if no matching record is found.

Apart from that your code works fine for me, although OSX requires `ns_c_in` instead of `C_IN`.

Try testing with `_nicname._tcp.us.` instead of `www.example.com`.

Comment: I've tried to do the SRV query to several domains now and it seems that it's just random when some sites return the SRV record. The suggested `_nicname._tcp.us` first returned nothing, but after sometime it gave me an answer. The same happened when I tried to do the SRV query with `dig` and `nslookup`commands. I thought that every domain returns at least something when they get the SRV query. Also I found some other suggested sites like `_sip._udp_columbia.edu` and it behaves exactly the same way: Sometimes it returns the record and sometimes it doesn't.